Are tentacle monsters really as common in anime as jokes and folks claim them to be?
A common stereotype about anime,  and to a lesser extent, manga, is that it is filled with tentacle monsters/demons, and that they are almost always violating a schoolgirl.
I know they are definitely a thing in anime, especially hentai, but I want to know HOW common of a thing it is in both hentai and normal anime and manga.
I have been into anime and manga for years now, and honestly have seen little of it without going out of my way to see it, but as there are folks that have been watching longer than me and also that there are tons of series, I thought I would ask.

It's a thing in video games as well, that's why Resident Evil 3 remake added this... fan service when the original didn't have it. It's only really common in hentai; normal anime are just plagued by panty shots and some other cliches.

Related/possible duplicate: Why are tentacles prevalent in anime?

Related, not the same; that one asks why it is common, I ask if it is. @AkiTanaka

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tentacle_erotica (Warning: contains NSFW content)

It's extremely uncommon in anime and ero-anime (hentai).
The notoriety stems from the late 1980s and early 1990s where grotesque monsters - some of them featuring tentacles - were popular, especially in OVAs. One such OVA is 3x3 Eyes (Sazan Eyes) from 1991. In episode 2 this happens (warning: sensitive image):

 

The key point here is that those were gory stories about fighting monsters. Those attacked and killed, but didn't have sex for pleasure. Not even in otherwise pornographic anime of that era.
There were a few exceptions of pornographic anime where tentacles are used in a sexual way, though. For example Injuu Gakuen La Blue Girl from 1992. That one is a parody with a ninja girl fighting demons and has a very lighthearted tone, despite things like this happening (warning: NSFW image):

 

Since those days tentacles have become a bit of an in-joke within the industry that gets referenced in various anime occasionally. Often it's just the tentacles without a proper monster attached, too.
If you specify tentacles with a monster attached that violate a schoolgirl then there are only very few anime that qualify. Tentacles themselves are a bit more common in ero-anime. About 10-15% of hentai feature a tentacle in some form or another.

There is a reason the tentacles trope came to be, as you can gleam from this incomplete list of anime and manga where naughty tentacles appear in that it is not "extremely uncommon" in anime, especially anime of the ecchi/hentai categories. From the top of my head, I can already think of Devil Hunter Yohko and Bastard...

...which do not appear in that list, but feature tentacles or slimes or snakes or other things shaped like tentacles engaging in some kind of violation against women or girls. We might need some numbers to be scientific, but you get the idea: any avid anime viewer is likely to encounter the tentacles trope or some extensions of that.

@Gao As mentioned, tentacles themselves are somewhat common, but tentacles with a monster attached that do rape a schoolgirl are uncommon. Don't forget that there are nearly 20.000 anime in existence. I bet you can't even find 200 titles (1% of all anime) that tick all three checkboxes.

Well, showing rape in an anime is already a very high bar restricted to late-night anime and adult OVAs. I was thinking more along the lines of mild fan service, like binding a girl with tentacles, and the question, a little unclear on what it is asking, didn't explicitly ask for rape anyways. Otherwise, I agree with your points.

@Gao I've been going off the first sentence of the question: "filled with tentacle monsters/demons, and that they are almost always violating a schoolgirl". Violation is the new political correct word to spell rape in porn.

@Ocean violate somebody (literary or old-fashioned) to force somebody to have sex. Everything new is old again.
